# Set Query Band with Spring JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, teradata

I am currently writing an app using Spring Boot-JPA connecting to a Teradata Database.

My requirement is to use Set Query_Band like this:

```
SET QUERY_BAND='someKey=someValue;' FOR TRANSACTION;
```

This is required for all the DB calls.

Is there any way i can have this generically instead of writing a query and invoking it in Spring JPA.

Comment: SET QUERY BAND = 'name=value; name2=value;' FOR SESSION|TRANSACTION;

Comment: You'll have to tell the database at some point during the session (after connecting) what the query band is. Perhaps write up a class to establish the connection, set the query band and return the connection object for your downstream SQL?